# Where can I find the reason of classing this hadith as Da’if by Al-Albani?

Tags: hadith, reference-request

I've been informed that this hadith is Da'if according to Al-Albani:

> Narrated Ma'qil bin Yasar:
>
> that the Prophet (ﷺ) said:
>
> > "Whoever says three times when he gets up in the morning: 'A'udhu Billahis-Sami Al-'Alim Min Ash-Shaitanir-Rajim' and he recites three Ayat from the end of Surah Al-Hashr - Allah appoints seventy-thousand angels who say Salat upon him until the evening. If he dies on that day, he dies a martyr, and whoever reaches the evening, he holds the same status."
> >     ‏
>
> [English reference  : Vol. 5, Book 42, Hadith 2922
>
>   Arabic reference    : Book 45, Hadith 3172](https://sunnah.com/urn/631660)

At Al-Maktaba.org, in this book [صحيح وضعيف سنن الترمذي](https://al-maktaba.org/book/782/2922) of Al-Albani, I can only see the grade which is Da'if. 
Here, only the hadith and the grade is given, but the reason is not present.

In that website, I found only these two books, [ضعيف سنن الترمذي](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1216) and [صحيح وضعيف سنن الترمذي](https://al-maktaba.org/book/782/2922) of Albani regarding the Hadith of Tirmizi. In [صحيح وضعيف سنن الترمذي](https://al-maktaba.org/book/782/2922), it's easy to find out the hadith but the reason is not given. And in [ضعيف سنن الترمذي](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1216), it's so much hard for me to find out the hadith but I've seen the reason of the grade of different Hadith.

I hope that the reason of the the grade of the cited hadith may be present there. But it's so much hard for me to find out the Hadith there because I can't understand the arrangement of the Hadith there. So I can't find the hadith there.

Generally, the scholars of Hadith, don't declare any classification of Hadith without presenting any reason. They present reason, then they class a Hadith, especially in case the unacceptable hadith (Da'if and Mawdoo).

So I want to know what is reason presented by Albani for classing this Hadith as Da'if.

And plz give the link of the website where the explanation is given, so that I can see the explanation and show it to others with reference and link. If one can give the link from Al-Maktaba.org, then it would be more beneficial for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked text says:

[image]

This mentions the grading of the Hadith based on Al-Albani's opinion, and gives cross-references to other books and the respective number of the hadith in each of them. The reason may be explained in one of those references. For example see it in hadith 342 in [إرواء](https://shamela.ws/book/22592/380#p5)

Answer (score 0):

ٱلسَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمْ وَرَحْمَةُ ٱللَّٰهِ وَبَرَكَاتُهُ

Here's Shaykh Zubayr 'Alī Za'ī's reason for weakening it:

من قال حین یصبح ثلات مرات
إسنادہ ضعیف باب (22)
خالد بن طہمان اختلط ولم یثبت أنہ حدث بہ قبل اختلاطہ (تقدم : 2484)
انوار الصحیفہ صفحہ نمبر: 274